# Why does this sql query take a long time?

Tags: mysql, octobercms

This query in an OctoberCMS website, which is built with Laravel. It takes about 580 ms to execute! What's the problem with it? and how to faster it?

```
SELECT * 
FROM   system_files 
WHERE  system_files.attachment_type = 'Me\Articles\Models\Article' 
       AND system_files.attachment_id = '235017' 
       AND field = 'image' 
       AND system_files.attachment_id IS NOT NULL 
ORDER  BY sort_order ASC 
LIMIT  1
```

The table has about 220,000 records, and these are the indexes on table:

```
field
attachment_id
attachment_type
```

Comment: try to add indexes to the where fields

Comment: There are already 3 indexes, I updated the question with them.

Comment: Is it a shared database, or under heavy load?

Comment: You don't need `system_files.attachment_id is not null` as you are already filtering it out with `system_files.attachment_id = '235017'`. If that field is not string, you may want to change it to `system_files.attachment_id = 235017`.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/using-explain.html

Comment: Is your ORDER BY clause causing a table scan?